# How is this image of an actor made to appear in the audience?

Tags: film-techniques

During the TV broadcast of the **3rd Asianet Comedy Awards**, a famous Malayalam actor (Jagathi Sreekumar) was seen in the audience. This baffled me, since he has been paralysed for the last several years and has not travelled much. When I watched the re-telecast, it was clarified that this was accomplished using "new digital technology." What is this technology? I've never seen it used before. Here's a video of the feat:

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that just looks like chromakey, with a space left in the audience for him to be imposed upon...? The angle of filming  him (looking upward) increases the realism.

Comment: I'm unable to watch the clip because I'm not in India. Does the camera move? If so, the "new" part may be connecting 2 motion-controlled cameras  over a network.

Comment: According to the effects which are quite "poor" (it's a live thing and not a blockbuster with people fixing issues afterwards), I'd say that the actor was inside "his home" with a green screen behind him and added in the broadcast. Like people do for meteo broadcasts in other words. The light around him doesn't match the one. I guess he had also a screen showing him what was on scene.

Comment: totally fake.  I can tell by the pixels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with the comment from EvilDr: this looks like simple chromakey. Specifically, there was a space in the audience between the man in the pink shirt and the man in the blue shirt. An image or video of Jagathi Sreekumar was added in between them. (I can't watch the video you included, because I'm in the United States, so my answer is based on the still image.)

One thing to note:  There is no shadow on the red carpet underneath his wheelchair. There are normal-looking shadows underneath the other men's feet. This commonly happens with chromakey.

[image]

Since this is the *3rd Asianet **Comedy** Awards*, I suspect that they were joking when they called this "new digital technology".

Comment: Brand new 80 year old technology